# How to regex a particular array variable from code string

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to regular expressions and struggling to extract the content of an array inside a code string with python. The output should be a list containing the elements of the particular array in the code string.

Assume this text structure (multilines included) in my code.txt file I want to regex:

```
Some code
var array = [
    element1,
    ...
    elementN
    ]
Some more code
```

My best approach so far was with following pattern:

```
pattern = r"var array = \[\s*(.*)"
```

This gave me the first element of the array using re.findall(). The only thing missing in this pattern is "do until ]".

Many thanks for any help beforehand!

Comment: `r"var array = \[.*?\]"gs` [regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/b8LQOG/1/)

Comment: Although this will work for your example, this won't work for many others. RegEx are not suited to parse code. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/jSejlK/2) Consider using a proper parser

Answer (score 2):

Just define the closing bracket in your regex:

```
pattern = r"var array = \[\s*(.*)\s*\]"
```

There is a really good [site](https://regex101.com/), where you can test your regular expressions, which also give hints on what you are doing:

Comment: You need the flag `s`, so the dot `.` matches the new line

Comment: Corrected it. If you want to use the `s` flag, you have to provide it as flag argument to the function: `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to loop inside a regular expression. The easy solution here is to first match everything between the brackets and split and strip the contents. Here is some example code.

```
import re

code = r"""
Some code
var array = [
    element1,
    element2,
    elementN
    ]
Some more code
"""

elements = [element.strip() for element in re.search(r"var array = \[([\s\S]*)\]", code).group(1).split(",")]

print(elements)
```